# Create Macro to delete rows based on cell value in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with almost 70,000 rows of data. I want to create a macro to delete rows, based on cell value in multiple columns. 
(i.e. delete all rows where Description (column 2) contains spare, and also delete all rows where SerialNumber (column 1) starts with SAM) 
So far, I have this code to delete all rows where Description contains SPARE.
How can I update this macro to filter on multiple items in the Description column, as well as multiple conditions in the SerialNumber column? Please see below link to screenshot of my data.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, "SPARE", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

This has to be a macro, as I'm going to be doing the identical filters on multiple spreadsheets each day.

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

Comment: You will want to start at the end and step backwards or you will end up unintentionally skipping rows.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: have you searched this site? there are dozens of questions about deleting rows and most of them use the backwards loop.

Comment: The macro that I'm using already works, it didn't skip any lines.

Comment: and yes, I searched the site. I didn't find any code that searches multiple cell values in different columns

Comment: @Deb in addition to the info on testing different cells in the linked answer, pay attention to how the rows are deleted.   Deleting one at a time as you  are now will be very slow

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

        If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "SPARE", vbTextCompare) Or _
           UCase(Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 3)) = "SAM" Then

            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work. Can you please explain exactly what this code is doing so I could try to figure it out?

Comment: @Deb Starting from the bottom row, it's checking every cell in column A for "SPARE", or if the value in column A starts with "SAM" - although in your example data I don't see any of those values - where are those located?